# Type Error when running function with Class

Tags: python, function, typeerror

I have a class named Individual, and I have a function based on it. When I run I get

---> 13     population: list[Individual], elite_size=0.1, new_pop=0.2

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

How can I get this to work?

```
def selection_rank_with_population_replacement_elite(
    population: list[Individual], elite_size=0.1, new_pop=0.2
) -> list[Individual]:

    sorted_individuals = sorted(population, key=lambda ind: ind.get_sharpe(), reverse=True)
    best_n_individuals = int(np.floor(len(sorted_individuals) * elite_size))
    new_individuals = int(np.floor(len(sorted_individuals) * new_pop))
    rank_distance = 1 / len(population)
    ranks = [(1 - i * rank_distance) for i in range(len(population))]
    ranks_sum = sum(ranks)
    selected = sorted_individuals[:best_n_individuals]

    for i in range(len(sorted_individuals) - best_n_individuals - new_individuals):
        shave = random.random() * ranks_sum
        rank_sum = 0
        for i in range(len(sorted_individuals)):
            rank_sum += ranks[i]
            if rank_sum > shave:
                selected.append(sorted_individuals[i])
                break
    new_individuals = [Individual.create_random() for _ in range(new_individuals)]
    selected.extend(new_individuals)

    return selected
```

Comment: I am on Python 3.8.10

Comment: I don't have version 3.8.10 to test on, but can confirm the problem on python 3.6.9. On 3.9.5 however, it does work without error. The error can be resolved by removing type hinting.

Comment: you cannot do this in python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work with Python 3.9+, but will not work with 3.8 or earlier.

With 3.8, using `typing.List` instead:

```
from typing import List

def selection_rank_with_population_replacement_elite(
    population: List[Individual], elite_size=0.1, new_pop=0.2
) -> list[Individual]:
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html (search for `typing.List` in there)

> [`typing.List` is] Deprecated since version 3.9: builtins.list now supports [].

Comment: PS: Note also the comment there recommending the use of `Sequence` or `Iterable` instead of `List` for function parameters: those would allow you to declare a more general function signature instead of accepting only lists.